# Connect to RDS MySQL programatically (NodeJs, Java) - ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, rds

I am trying to connect to my RDS (AWS MySQL database) using NodeJs mysql library.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

var connection;

connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
      port: 3306,
      user: "username",
      password: "MyPassword",
      database: "DbName",
    });
```

I was also trying mysql2 and sequelize. All of them got me the same result:

`{ 
  error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'username'@'myhost,
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlState: '28000'
}`

However, this remote database is set to public and I am able to connect to it with mysql command:

`mysql -u username -pMyPassowrd -h xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

I am also able to connect to it with MySQL Workbench.

Also, the problem is not in NodeJs, because I am able to connect to my local database:

```
connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'test',
    });
```

In conclusion, my AWS database is publicly available and I can connect to it, just not using NodeJs for some reason.

I have not found a useful answer yet. Did anyone encounter this problem ?

UPDATE:

Trying to connect in Java with simple Connection returns the same result as well:

```
final Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:/xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/DbName", "username", "MyPassword");
```

UPDATE 2:

I was missing one slash for Java code. I needed to use `jdbc:mysql://` instead of `jdbc:mysql:/`. But NodeJs implementation is still one big mystery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was rather simple, just add an **ssl** option with *true* value

```
connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
      port: 3306,
      user: "username",
      password: "MyPassword",
      database: "DbName",
      ssl: true //this does the trick
    });
```